# im having trouble with this code, although it works but not the way i want

Tags: python, while-loop

```
users = {
    "Armin": "1234",
    "Mehrnaz": "4321"
}

entered_username = input("Enter your username: ")
entered_password = input("Enter your password: ")

while entered_username in users and users[entered_username] != entered_password:
    print("Wrong, Try again")
    entered_username = input("username: ")
    entered_password = input("password: ")
else:
    print("You have logged in successfully ")
```

In this code if i put the right username and wrong password, I get the "Wrong, Try again", but if I put the wrong username and wrong password, i still get the "You have logged in successfully"

help please, thank you <3

Comment: entered_username  is not in users => The while condition is false. It goes to the else.

Comment: Try this `while users.get(entered_username) != entered_password`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're two conditions in your loop:

1. `entered_username in users` ;
2. `users[entered_username] != entered_password` .

If any of those conditions fail, your loop won't be started and `else` section will be executed.

When you enter username which doesn't exist in `users` dictionary first condition will be false.

You may use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) which will return `None` by default if key doesn't exist in dictionary and simplify your loop condition to:

```py
while users.get(entered_username) != entered_password:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
users = {
    "Armin": "1234",
    "Mehrnaz": "4321"
}

while True:
       
    entered_username = input("username: ")
    entered_password = input("password: ")
    if entered_username in users and users.get(entered_username)==entered_password:
        print ('Successfully logged in.')
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong, Try again")
```

Comment: is the ```entered_username in users``` part relevant ? I guess that ```users.get(entered_username)``` return ```None``` if the given key is not in the keys of the dict ?

Answer (score 0):

your condition in "While" is wrong. There should be:

```
while (entered_username not in users) or (users[entered_username] != entered_password):
```

Comment: this actually really helped with just "not" and "or"
thank you <3

Comment: @Armin, notice that there're two **not** inside expression (`not in`, `!=`) which you can factor out: `not(entered_username in users and users[entered_username] == entered_password)`.